# Haskell -- problem with pretty-printing a list

Tags: haskell, pretty-print, fizzbuzz

I'm new to haskell, and i read through and digested [Learn You A Haskell For Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/), trying out a couple of things along the way. For my first project i wanted to try the classic: FizzBuzz. So i came up with the following code:

```
import System.IO

fizzBuzz :: (Integral a) => a -> String
fizzBuzz num
    | fizz && buzz = "FizzBuzz"
    | fizz = "Fizz"
    | buzz = "Buzz"
    | otherwise = show num
    where fizz = num `mod` 3 == 0
          buzz = num `mod` 5 == 0

main = print $ map fizzBuzz [1..100]
```

Worked great, except i got a rather dense looking list that was hard to read. So i tried this main function instead:

```
main = map putStrLn $ map fizzBuzz [1..100]
```

And that gives me the error `Couldn't match expected type 'IO t' against inferred type '[IO ()]'`. I tried half a dozen things and none of it seemed to help. What's the proper way to do what i'm trying to do?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
putStrLn :: Show a => a -> IO ()
map putStrLn :: Show a => [a] -> [IO ()]
```

You've got a list of `IO ()` actions.

```
main :: IO ()
```

You need to join them into a single `IO ()` action.

What you want to do is to perform each of those `IO ()` actions in [sequence](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Prelude.html#v%3Asequence)/[sequence_](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Prelude.html#v%3Asequence_):

```
sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
sequence_ :: Monad m => [m a] -> m ()
```

For convenience, [mapM](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Prelude.html#v%3AmapM)/[mapM_](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Prelude.html#v%3AmapM_) will map a function over a list and sequence the resulting monadic results.

```
mapM :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]
mapM_ :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m ()
```

So your fixed code would look like this:

```
main = mapM_ putStrLn $ map fizzBuzz [1..100]
```

Although I'd probably write it like this:

```
main = mapM_ (putStrLn . fizzBuzz) [1..100]
```

Or even this:

```
main = putStr $ unlines $ map fizzBuzz [1..100]
```

---

Let's write our own `sequence`.  What do we want it to do?

```
sequence [] = return []
sequence (m:ms) = do
    x <- m
    xs <- sequence ms
    return $ x:xs
```

- If there's nothing left in the list, return (inject into the monad) an empty list of results.
- Otherwise, within the monad,

  - Bind (for the `IO` monad, this means execute) the first result.
  - `sequence` the rest of the list; bind that list of results.
  - Return a cons of the first result and the list of other results.

GHC's library uses something more like `foldr (liftM2 (:)) (return [])` but that's harder to explain to a newcomer; for now, just take my word that they're equivalent.

`sequence_` is easier, since it doesn't bother keeping track of the results.  GHC's library implements it as `sequence_ ms = foldr (>>) (return ()) ms`.  Let's just expand the definition of `foldr`:

```
  sequence [a, b, c, d]
= foldr (>>) (return ()) [a, b, c, d]
= a >> (b >> (c >> (d >> return ())))
```

In other words, "do `a`, discard the result; do `b`; discard the result, … finally, return `()`".

```
mapM  f xs = sequence  $ map f xs
mapM_ f xs = sequence_ $ map f xs
```

---

On the other hand, you don't even need to know monads at all with the alternate `unlines` solution.

What does `unlines` do?  Well, `lines "a\nb\nc\nd\n" = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]`, so of course `unlines ["a", "b", "c", "d"] = "a\nb\nc\nd\n"`.

`unlines $ map fizzBuzz [1..100]` = `unlines ["1", "2", "Fizz", ..]` = `"1\n2\nFizz\n..."` and off it goes to `putStr`.  Thanks to the magic of Haskell's laziness, the full string never needs to be constructed in memory, so this will happily go to `[1..1000000]` or higher :)

Comment: Thank you, i knew haskell had something like that but i couldn't figure it out! now to understand *why* it works... :)

Comment: As I tried to explain, you generated a list of `IO ()` actions, but you need to say *what* you want to do with them.  `sequence` runs a list of monads in order, which happens to be what you want here.  My last solution, instead, joins the fizz/buzz strings into a single multi-line string before it heads off into the strange land of `IO`.

Comment: Yep, i just didn't make the connection between a monad and an IO action -- some of that tutorial is still a little fuzzy